# .NET6 Blazor @typeparam where constraint ERROR RZ1017

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0, razor-components

I have this directive on top of razor component file but it throws an error
RZ1017

@typeparam TEntity where TEntity : IEntity

What I missed?

Basde from [.NET 6 Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#generic-type-parameter-support)

Comment: It helps when you include the error message as well. And is IEntity in scope?

Comment: Can you share your code sample?

Comment: I confirm that with VS 17.6 and .NET 6, I also have this error, which I cannot resolve.

Comment: Do you, by chance, have a "code behind" class? With this, I found out that I only have to use `@typeparam TEntity` and define the constraints on the `.razor.cs` file.

Comment: @rabejens This works for me. But leaves a bad feeling that it is something inconsistable in my code. Perhaps it is a bug in Visual Studio or its markup components, and when it will be fixed, I should correct my code returning all type constraints to the markup back.

Comment: @rabejens Your comment should be an accepted answer; thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

I've found a not so inconvenient workaround until this bug is fixed.

When I open or restart Visual Studio, I get syntax errors (the code still compiles fine):

[image: syntax error]

Edit the .csproj file, anything goes; just add a space -> save, then remove it and save again.

[image]

Go back the razor file, and the syntax error is no longer there:
[image]

Restarting Visual Studio will make the issue re-appear, so rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ASP.NET MVC project with .NET 6 and Server Side Blazor.
I had the same issue.

What fixed it, was adding this:
`<RazorLangVersion>latest</RazorLangVersion>`
in the csproj file of the project, under the tag `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>` .

Edit 1: so the above code actually did not work.
The proper version of RazorLangVersion is described [Razor language version](https://here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/sdk?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

In the section Razor language version, it is said that the version follows the SDK version.
I tested it again, placing the matching SDK version between the tags and still I have issues.

From this I can conclude that the problem is with VS itself.

Comment: When I use this RazorLangVersion tag with the "latest" value, I get multiple errors "Error CS1061 'RenderTreeBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddComponentParameter' and no accessible extension method 'AddComponentParameter' accepting a first argument of type 'RenderTreeBuilder' could be found". VS 2022 (17.6.2), .NET 6,7.

Comment: With these errors I can't compile and run my code. Without this tag I get a visual "many errors" mess in the editor, but at lest can compile and run. So it seems like there is a bug in Visual Studio or its Razor markup componets, or it should be something additionally changed somewhere, not just adding the RazorLangVersion tag.

Comment: I am not sure, but perhaps [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76482102/why-type-parameter-order-is-important-when-using-components) is also coupled with the one described here.